# Test cases to test Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2 API's

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, testcase, retrofit2

I have tried using robolectric and mockito inorder to test the retrofit APIs but didn't get any success doing so.

Can anyone help me with the same. If not robolectric and mockito what options can I try.

Have tried with this example here also. But its not working in my case

https://github.com/swanson/retrofit-demo/tree/master/Octodroid
Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: This thing that was linked is an eclipse project. That's outdated since 1.5 years ago. While not Robolectric, this setup enables JUnit unit tests: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html#0

Comment: Yes exactly. Can I get any reference for the latest retrofit lib using android studio

Comment: @EpicPandaForce or else can Retrofit 2.0.0 - beta2 APIs be tested using testcases

Comment: Check out this [link](http://riggaroo.co.za/retrofit-2-mocking-http-responses/)